# Extract parcel layers from vector pdf

Tags: shapefile, pdf, feature-extraction, vector

So, I have an interesting problem... I have a PDF file which has over 100 pages and each of these pages is displaying a map in vector format.

By using some third party program I was able to find out that one of these layers is a parcel layer.

Now, what I am trying to do here is extract just this layer for every page in this PDF document and then stitch each of the parcel layer pages back together.

I am looking for some program or script which will automate some or all parts of this without screwing up the parcel line geometry. Additionally, I am assuming that I probable will need to manually align each of the extracted vector parcel pages which I guess is fine but what I think I need for this to work is some type of basemap background, I was thinking if one script can extract all the parcel vectors and then some other program can load all of them into some mapping program, me manually alligning each page and then finally being able to "join" the seperate pages into one large parcel vector map that the same (or yet another gis program) can append the correct lat/long data and turn it into a shapefile.

Uggghhh, so... Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Comment: This could help. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/how-to-import-svg-into-gis

Comment: Even if technically possible, are you sure what you are doing is legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Aide Pdf to DXF converter to convert the pdf maps to dxf while you can open in either AutoCAD or ArcGIS to edit.

## Scholar