# How to get DXF to show up in the right spot?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, pdf, dxf

I just followed the advice of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/how-to-import-svg-into-gis) forum post in order to export the vector layers of a PDF for usage in ArcMap. The map vector layers in the PDF were spatially referenced. I was able to export the layers as a DXF using Inkscape and open the layers in ArcMap. I then went to the properties of the DXF in catalog and set the proper projection. However, when I brought the DXF into the map document, it was not showing up in the right location. It appears the the spatial information was somehow removed in the process of exporting into a DXF. Does anyone know of a solution to my situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your InkScape step but there is Online Help [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001000000010000000) on how to go about Georeferencing CAD datasets such as DXF for display in ArcMap.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, thanks for your respone. Spatial Adjustment only works if you have a vector to reference the DXF to. In my case, I do not have anything to reference the DXF to, I need to figure out how to preserve the vector's spatial information from the PDF and bring it into ArcMap. If someone knows of a diff workflow, I am open to that too.

Comment: I'm thinking that you should be able to read off some point values in your PDF and use those to create a few point features to use as your control.