# SVG To Shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gdal, svg

Is it possible to draw out some SVG shapes in Illustrator or Inkscape and convert them to Shapefile using GDAL or QGIS (or something else perhaps?).

I have an image that I can easily georeference, but there are many shapes I would like to draw out and using a tool like GIMP to draw them out would be much easier than using QGIS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that pstoedit is your best bet:  http://www.pstoedit.net/pstoedit/

Based on similar question:

[How to Import SVG into GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/how-to-import-svg-into-gis)