# Converting an SVG into to another map projection using QGIS

Tags: qgis

Basically, I have a map made in affinity designer that I would like to convert into a few different projections while still retaining the vector information.  I’d then export it back to affinity designer.

I’m still very much a beginner – the only thing I have used QGIS for before is to georeference a raster in order to change its projection. So far, I cannot even work out how to bring my SVG into QGIS.

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/importing-svg-into-gis and see if some of those answers help. It is possible that the georeference is lost, like with non-GeoPDF, vectors exist but are expressed in page units and don't have correct geolocation, if this is the case have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/georeferencing-vector-layer-with-control-points-using-qgis and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Micheal.  I tried the first option but I couldn't work out how to set the coordinates of the DXF - when I converted the SVG it just chose default coordinates that were different to mine.  The SVG was never georeferenced in the first place.  Do you know if there is a way select the coordinates as the out dimensions of the SVG e.g. the bottom of my map lines up with 77 degrees south. In the second post stu's answer seems good but a bit to complicated for me.   Sorry if any of my wording is a little off.

Comment: I've had to do this a few times with PDF-DXF, because the coordinates are in page units. Another post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22691/georeferencing-dxf-using-qgis which talks about world file for DXF, if you understand how to georeference a raster then convert SVG->BMP and georeference the bitmap then copy the parameters to the CAD world file (.wld), I use BMP as they only support world file (external) georeference and not tags. **It is critical that both DXF and BMP have the same page extent and that the georeference occurs in the same CRS the SVG was created in**.

Comment: Do you know if there is a video anywhere showing this process? I have never interacted with wld files and wouldn't know where to start.  How do I check if the DXF and BMP have the same extent?

Comment: I doubt there's a video, it is a bit of a hack. Normally I wouldn't regress a map product to vector if there is any chance of obtaining the vector from the custodian. There is a writing https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/cad/world-files-for-cad-datasets.htm about the format of WLD files, they're a control point transformation which is what you export from the georeferencer, As for confirming they're the same extent set a dummy world for the DXF using a scale of the DPI of the BMP, if they're the same extent the vector lines from the DXF will overlay on the raster BMP.